# Authenticated users can't edit their own content even with permissions set accordingly

Tags: users

As an authenticated user, I've created a node. The Tasks menu is completely absent. If I try to access it via node/476/edit, I see "Access Denied".

The Task menu (edit, view, revisions) is seen by the Administrator but Authenticated users. How can I bedug this further?

However, I have permission set for this Content Type as follows below. I've included another Node TYpe called Event as well. 
[image]
[image]

I even tried looking into the table node_type to see if anything was off

```
       type: user_posted_content
       name: User Posted Content
       base: node_content
     module: node
description: Postings by users 
       help: 
  has_title: 1
title_label: Title
     custom: 1
   modified: 1
     locked: 0
   disabled: 0
  orig_type: user_posted_content
```

**Other Modules**
I previously had tried both Content Access (content_access) and Node view permissions (node_view_permissions) but ended up deactivating both.

**Digging deeper**
It appears I may have some residual from one of those modules.

```
MariaDB [s7data]> select * from node_access where nid = 476;
+-----+-----+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| nid | gid | realm | grant_view | grant_update | grant_delete |
+-----+-----+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| 476 |   0 | all   |          1 |            0 |            0 |
+-----+-----+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Do you have any other permissions or access modules in place, like Nodeaccess or Taxonomy Access Control?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Yes, Node view permissions (node_view_permissions) and Content Access (content_access) were installed. Comment upvote.

Comment: You might want to completely uninstall these modules and rebuild permissions /admin/reports/status/rebuild   Also, another question: is auth user able to edit other content-types, or is this a global problem?

Comment: Answer updated. Yes. It's system wide and I've tried to rebuild permissions.

Comment: Did you uninstall the modules? That should hopefully remove their data. If not, you might have to delete their data manually. Another option would be to install the NodeAccess module, then remove any restrictions you added previously from the Nodeaccess config page, save, and then uninstall module.

Comment: No I just disabled. Luckily I still have a back up (on another server). If the uninstall doesn't work. I'll copy updated content (via copy paste) and then bring that database back over. Another comment upvote to thank you. Could you put something in the answer area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to restore your database, you only need to enable your nodeaccess module in your modules page and it should restore on its own and you will have access to all stored data. Then go to nodeaccess config, undo all the restrictions, save, then go back to modules page and uninstall nodeaccess. And rebuild permissions. Hopefully that'd do the trick!